# Materialize:How to programmatically open and close collapsibles

Tags: javascript, materialize

Trying to execute the open() method of on a specific collapsible element in  **Materialize** inside DOM using the following function:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
        var options = {};
        var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems);
        console.log(instances);
        instances.open(1);    
    });
```

And getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: instances.open is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

Comment: I think `document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible')` will give you an array, if there is only a single element/query you might probably need to do something like this `document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible')[0]` 
Ps: Haven't used Vanila JS for sometime now so can't be sure

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `init` for initialising the `collapsible` and then with that instance you can use all collapsible `methods`.

```
var elems = document.querySelector('.collapsible');
var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems);
instances.open(1);
```